# Setting a timeout for MySQLi query execution

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, timeout

I am exploring the possibility of setting a timeout/stopping a specific query in PHP and MySQLi.

Slightly modified example from *php.net*:

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT NESTED MYSQL QUERY HERE.")) {
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $city);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->set_timeout("50000"); //hypothetical, will not work
    $stmt->bind_result($district);
    while($stmt->fetch()){ 
        //to do
    }
}
$mysqli->close();
```

Is this possible?

Ideal implementation:

1. Inside PHP code and not through configuration of MySQL server
2. Can be implemented only for selected queries and not to all queries
3. Works (at a minimum) on MySQL 5.6 and beyond
4. Can inform the end user, e.g.

> The process took long than expected. Try to split your dataset into
>   segments.

Answer (score -1):

Refer this

http://mysqlserverteam.com/server-side-select-statement-timeouts/

For  read-only SELECT statement

```
SELECT 
MAX_STATEMENT_TIME = 2000 --in milliseconds
* 
FROM table;
```

Comment: Documentation says: _This option was added in MySQL 5.7.4. It was removed in MySQL 5.7.8._ What about for lower versions?

Answer (score -1):

```
function querylimit($Link,$Query,$Limit){
    $Link->query($Query,MYSQLI_ASYNC);
    $retries = 0;
    do{
        $changed[] = $errored[] = $empty[] =$Link;
        $poll_result = mysqli_poll($changed,$errored,$empty,1);
        if($poll_result === false){
            return true;
        }
        if($poll_result > 0 && !empty($changed)){
            return true;
        }
        if($retries++ >= $Limit){
            $Link->kill($Link->thread_id);
            return false;
        }
    }while(true);
}

querylimit($mysqli,"select sleep(30)",5);
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.